# Java Native Hook stuck in an endless loop

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Hey there so I am coding an autoclicker that starts clicking when holding down my left mouse button. My issue is that it does not stop clicking when I release it! I would appreciate any help! My code so far is as follows!

```
public void nativeMouseClicked(NativeMouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Mouse Clicked: " + e.getClickCount());
}

public static boolean released;

public void nativeMouseReleased(NativeMouseEvent e) {
    released=true;
}

public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent e) {

    released = false;

        while(released != true) {
            try {
                Mouse.sendLeftClick();
            } catch (AWTException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            double deviation = 31;
            double mean = 95;
            int min = 65;
            int max = 117;
            Random r = new Random();
            double randGauss = (r.nextGaussian() * deviation);
            long delayPreClamp = Math.round(randGauss + mean);
            long delay = (long) MathUtil.clamp(delayPreClamp, min, max);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
}

public void nativeMouseMoved(NativeMouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Mouse Moved: " + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY());
}

public void nativeMouseDragged(NativeMouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Mouse Dragged: " + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY());
}

static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
        GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
    }
    catch (NativeHookException ex) {
        System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

        System.exit(1);
    }

    // Construct the example object.
    Inter inter = new Inter();

    // Add the appropriate listeners.
    GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(inter);
    GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseMotionListener(inter);
}
```

Thanks in advance folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are blocking the event thread with your while loop in `nativeMousePressed`. You will need to do this processing in a different thread.

Look at `Thread`, `ExecutorService`, etc.